# Action Form beans inheritance

Tags: struts-1

We have a Action Form bean which has common elements and other action forms 
inherit this Action Form.The parent action form is in a different module and rest of the action forms are in a different module.Parent module is used as dependency in child module so we don't have compile time errors.But while trying to access the particular action we get child class action form can not be cast to struts Action Form. Please help on this.

Comment: Parent class Action form bean extends the struts validator form which extends the Action form.In weblogic we were not getting any error but after migrating to jboss we   
 are getting error.

Comment: can give an minimal example and the error?

Comment: Will upload the code tomorrow. You can follow below link .We have the same situation.
https://coderanch.com/t/51340/frameworks/inheritance-struts

Comment: That does not appear to be the same situation--that's a simple inheritance question that doesn't involve separate modules. What "modules" are you referring to here?